# openresty on body_filter_by_lua send socket

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have a demand, is at server return response, send a request to other server, but openresty say API disabled in the context of body_filter_by_lua*. i use module resty.http.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the main logic.

First issue subrequest to your upstream (location.capture or lua-resty-http)

Upon success you may first send the response downstream by Lua code and issue the next subrequest to your "other server" from Lua.

UPDATE - this doesn't work
*As second approach you may treat your "other server" as upstream and allow request to this upstream only if subrequest to original server will be successful.*

For both scenarios you may use access_by_lua* and content_by_lua* where cosocket API is available.

Comment: in access_by_lua*, can't get response status, and in content_by_lua_*, i don't how to  return html to user. 1: user -> server 2: server-> send current request -> other server 3: server -> send current response -> other server  4:  return current response to user, not lua say or other. just server return

Comment: I don't understand your question. You may use ngx.say() to return html wiithin content_by_lua*

Comment: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture has good enough documentation about returned response, including status

Comment: i have see this document. i maybe return custom response, or return origin response. how to use ngx.say return origin response?

Comment: not just this. the first is  get response status, and second is return origin response to user... but in content_by_lua need lua generate response.. i know how to get resposne status, but i don't know how to return origin response to user in content_by_lua_*. do u  understand what i mean? friend... thx

Comment: Has been solved.in header_filter, i set content_len is nil, and body change body.. be work